# oauth_verifier is not passed using DotNetOpenAuth's Webconsumer

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I receive back a good oauth_verifier value from the server, but it is not being passed on via the `ProcessUserAuthorization` call to the access_token endpoint.

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth 3.3.1, and the WebConsumer implementation.
The server I'm working with is using OAuth 1.0a not 1.0.1.

Do I need to force DotNetOpenAuth to use 1.0a?

```
2010-01-16 13:19:44,343 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel [(null)] <(null)> - After binding element processing, the received UserAuthorizationResponse (1.0.1) message is: 
    oauth_verifier: dEz9lE9AA1gcdr6oCbmD
    oauth_token: vauHNVOCITlbGCuqycWn

2010-01-16 13:19:44,346 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel [(null)] <(null)> - Preparing to send AuthorizedTokenRequest (1.0) message.
2010-01-16 13:19:44,346 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings [(null)] <(null)> - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.OAuthHttpMethodBindingElement applied to message.
2010-01-16 13:19:44,346 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings [(null)] <(null)> - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardReplayProtectionBindingElement applied to message.
2010-01-16 13:19:44,346 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings [(null)] <(null)> - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings.StandardExpirationBindingElement applied to message.
2010-01-16 13:19:44,346 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel [(null)] <(null)> - Applying secrets to message to prepare for signing or signature verification.
2010-01-16 13:19:44,348 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings [(null)] <(null)> - Signing AuthorizedTokenRequest message using HMAC-SHA1.
2010-01-16 13:19:44,349 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings [(null)] <(null)> - Constructed signature base string: GET&http%3A%2F%2Fx-staging.indivo.org%3A8000%2Foauth%2Faccess_token&oauth_consumer_key%3Doak%26oauth_nonce%3DgPersiZV%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1263676784%26oauth_token%3DvauHNVOCITlbGCuqycWn%26oauth_version%3D1.0
2010-01-16 13:19:44,349 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Bindings [(null)] <(null)> - Binding element DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.SigningBindingElementChain applied to message.
2010-01-16 13:19:44,351 [5] INFO  DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel [(null)] <(null)> - Prepared outgoing AuthorizedTokenRequest (1.0) message for http://x-staging.indivo.org:8000/oauth/access_token: 
    oauth_token: vauHNVOCITlbGCuqycWn
    oauth_consumer_key: XXXXXXmyComsumerKeyXXXXXX
    oauth_nonce: gPersiZV
    oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
    oauth_signature: xNynvr2oFlqtdoOKOl2ETiiTLGY=
    oauth_version: 1.0
    oauth_timestamp: 1263676784

2010-01-16 13:19:44,351 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel [(null)] <(null)> - Sending AuthorizedTokenRequest request.
2010-01-16 13:19:44,351 [5] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Http [(null)] <(null)> - HTTP GET http://x-staging.indivo.org:8000/oauth/access_token
2010-01-16 13:20:34,657 [5] ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Http [(null)] <(null)> - WebException from http://x-staging.indivo.org:8000/oauth/access_token: 
<h4>Internal Server Error</h4>
```

[A pastebin link to the log4net log](http://pastebin.com/m5aff6d30)

Comment: Can you include the log4net logs of the process so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @Andrew, let me know if the log file link is unreadable.

As I understand it, the oauth_verifier should have been passed to the AccessTokenEndpoint, but I dont see it (nor did the server)

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth uses 1.0.1 to refer to 1.0a since it uses a Version object which doesn't support letters in versions, so that's not the issue.

Comment: BozoJoe, I don't see a log file link anywhere.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m5aff6d30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the log, you'll see that DotNetOpenAuth received the verifier message and recognized it as a 1.0a message where the log says "received UserAuthorizationResponse (1.0.1)" (since 1.0.1 is DNOA's way of saying 1.0a).

You'll also note from the log that DNOA sends a "AuthorizedTokenRequest (1.0)" message.  This strongly suggests that the `ServiceProviderDescription` object that you've passed to the `WebConsumer` instance with a `ProtocolVersion` property set to `V10` instead of `V10a`.

You *may* be initializing the `ServiceProviderDescription` correctly when you first send the user to the Service Provider, but initializing it without setting its version number the second time when you call `WebConsumer.ProcessAuthorization`.

Another possibility is that the Service Provider is violating the OAuth 1.0a spec, and DotNetOpenAuth detects this and overrides your setting and decides to treat the service provider as merely an OAuth 1.0 service provider.  If this is what's happening, you see your own `ServiceProviderDescription` object's `ProtocolVersion` property change from 1.0.1 to 1.0, and your log will include this substring "Expected OAuth service provider at endpoint"...

Comment: so this message >>

Expected OAuth service provider at endpoint DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.MessageReceivingEndpoint to use OAuth 1.0.1 but 1.0 was detected.  Adjusting service description to new version.
<<
is telling me that the SP is violating the 1.0a spec?  Can I live with that, and still pass the verifier back to the AccessTokenEndpoint?

Comment: thanks Andrew, the SP is replying to the request token without a oauth_callback_confirmed specified. Looks like that pushed the version back to 1.0.  I forced the version back up to 1.0a before doing ProcessUserAuthorization(), and that change is sending the verifier in the body.

Comment: Cool.  I'm glad you've found a workaround.  I hope you'll also email the SP guys and tell them they've got a bug.